# Multiple PDF + Excel list

Tags: pdf, split

i am trying to do something a bit difficult (for me) here. So i have a PDF with over a 100 pages and an excel sheet with all the corresponding names of each page. 
So what i want is a way to split the PDF into individual PDFs and rename them according to the excel sheet. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Acrobat?
There is a function to split PDFs by pages, book marks etc in there.  I am sure other PDF editing software has a similar feature.

You can then write a VBA script or similar to read the Excel and rename the files, if you are comfortable with code: [How to rename multiple pdf files used excel database vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333764/how-to-rename-multiple-pdf-files-used-excel-database-vba)

Or you could try a file name changing software, something like http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php